# Increase height of UIView without Auto Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I need to create an "old" style UIView, without AutoLayout and constraints. In my view, there is a table view which is calculating it's size with auto layout and another view. Unfortunately it appears, that the view itself doesn't provide the height I need. This is how I am creating the UIView:

```
// View 1 - Calendar View

FSCalendar *calendar = [[FSCalendar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, height)];
calendar.dataSource = self;
calendar.delegate = self;

calendar.scopeGesture.enabled = YES;

[view addSubview:calendar];

// View 2 - TableView

_myTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.myTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    self.myTableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
    self.myTableView.backgroundColor = self.view.backgroundColor;
    [self.myTableView  setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.myTableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
  //  self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0;
    self.myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    _myTableView.bounces = NO;
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.myTableView.delegate = self;
    self.myTableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(@"8.4") && (IS_IPAD)){
        self.myTableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
    }

    [self.view addSubview:_myTableView];
```

I suppose problem might be here:

```
_myTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

Because, I'm missing about 200 points of space (y position that I want to programmatically move the table view down).

Is there any way to fit screen height to my views?

Comment: in which method you are write this code?

Comment: @JayeshThanki in view did load

Comment: I didn't get why you take 200 as y origin in "_myTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
"?       
either make 200 to 0 or SCREEN_HEIGHT to (SCREEN_HEIGHT-200) .  Hope this helps.

Comment: @SatishA 200 is height of another view that are on top (calendar). So i simply move table down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this view is inside another view, it should be resized in `layoutSubviews`.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // your code here...
}
```

If it is inside of a viewController's view do the resizing in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    // your code here...
}
```

Comment: surely you would do this with Swift, guys

Comment: Doesn't really make a difference: autolayout can be used or avioded in obj-c or swift